# como puedo insertar en la tabla todos los datos de la consulta y no solo tome el primer dato que me regrese la consulta?

Tags: php, sql

```
$conexion= new mysqli($host, $usuario, $contraseña, $base);
if ($conexion -> connect_errno) 
{
    die("Fallo la conexion:(".$conexion -> mysqli_connect_errno().")".$conexion -> mysqli_connect_error());
}

$Query="call insertCons('$select')";
$resQuery = $conexion ->query($Query);

{
      $idSIM=$registroQuery['idSimulation'];
      $idSAP=$registroQuery['idSAP'];
      $Component=$registroQuery['Description'];
      $WC_Family=$registroQuery['WC_Family'];
      $STD=$registroQuery['FG_StdPack'];
      $RacksPerSAP=round($registroQuery['(products.DailyDemand/family.FG_StdPack)']*$DaysOfTheWeek);
      $TakttimeSAP=round($MinPWeek/$RacksPerSAP);
}

$conexion= new mysqli($host, $usuario, $contraseña, $base);
if ($conexion -> connect_errno) 
{
    die("Fallo la conexion:(".$conexion -> mysqli_connect_errno().")".$conexion -> mysqli_connect_error());
}

$FilledINConsumptions= "INSERT INTO consumptions (idSimulation, idSAP, Component, WC_Family, Dates, Quantity)
    VALUES ('$idSim', '$idSAP', '$Component', '$WC_Family', '$Minutes', '$STD')";

if ($conexion->query($FilledINConsumptions) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $FilledINConsumptions . "<br>" . $conexion->error;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente tu solucion sea hacer la logica del lado de SQL con [INSERT INTO SELECT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp):

```
INSERT INTO table2
    SELECT * FROM table1
    WHERE condition;
```

Tu caso creo que vendria a ser algo como:

```
"INSERT INTO consumptions " . $Query
```

Donde tu query realizaria las operaciones de rendondeo y mulitplicacino/division.

De no tener la posibilidad de realizar todo desde SQL, deberas iterar sobre cada uno de los registros e insertarlos dentro de la tabla (ejemplo no funcional):

```
$FilledINConsumptions= "INSERT INTO consumptions (idSimulation, idSAP, Component, WC_Family, Dates, Quantity)
    VALUES ('$valores[0]'), ('$valores[1]'), ('$valores[2]'),..."
```